# array.splice returining a value twice

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this function that replaces an array element at indexOf(before) with a string called "after". This almost works fine except I'm getting two "after" values instead of just one

here is my code:

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  var strArr = []; 
  strArr = str.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    strArr.splice(strArr.indexOf(before), 1, after);
  }
  return strArr;
}

myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped");
```

and here what it returns:

["A", "quick", "brown", "fox", "leaped", "over", "the", "lazy", "leaped"]

what is wrong?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @gurvinder372 ["A", "quick", "brown", "fox", "leaped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]

Comment: so you simply want to replace `jumped` with `leaped`?

Comment: yup that is what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah the problem here is rather unlucky! This is because after it finds element 4, indexOf returns -1 (its way of saying not found), and replaces the last (-1) from the array.

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  var strArr = []; 
  strArr = str.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    var index = strArr.indexOf(before);
    if(index!=-1){
        strArr.splice(index, 1, after);
    }
  }
  return strArr;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to replace, then keep it simple

```js
var regex = new RegExp("jumped", "gi");
var output = "A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".replace( regex, "leaped" );
console.log(output);
```

You can read more about `RegExp` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 1):

Array.prototype.splice returns -1 when no element is found : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

So in the first loop, it will replace "jumped" by "leaped" as expected, but for all other, it will do `strArr(-1, 1, after)` which means it will replace the last element with `after`.

The problem here is your for loop, it checks if before is present for **every element in your table**. You must use a while loop as in the example provided in the link above (look at Finding all the occurrences of an element)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
   var strArr = []; 
   strArr = str.split(' ');
   for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
      if(strArr[i] === before){
         strArr[i] = after;
      }
   }
   return strArr;
}

myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped");
```